# Realm Encryption, Secure Enclave, and Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, realm, keychain

Sorry to be yet another post about encryption, but I am struggling with setting up some truly strong encryption in my application. I currently have a basic setup for login that utilizes keychain and is based off of [Tim Mitra's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/147308/secure-ios-user-data-keychain-touch-id), which works wonderfully. However, I am uncomfortable about storing the account email / username in UserDefaults as it isn't particularly secure. **Is there a better method that anyone can come up with?** Additionally, I am working on utilizing Realm's built in encryption features, however I am unsure as to how I should properly store the key for said encryption given that it is of type Data. I also have heard that I should double encrypt the user's credentials using Secure Enclave and possibly utilize the same technique with Realm's key. **Is there a guide that someone could point me to?** **How would you better optimize my code to be brutally secure?** I have already set the application to check the device for Cydia and other signs of jailbreaking so as to avoid keychain data dumps and plan on checking any / all urls called too.

Here's my implementation of Keychain:

```
private func setupAccount()
{
    let newAccountName = inputFields[0].text
    let newPassword = inputFields[1].text
    let hasLoginKey = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasSetup")
    if !hasLoginKey {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(inputFields[0].text, forKey: "username")
    }

    do {

        // This is a new account, create a new keychain item with the account name.
        let passwordItem = KeychainLIPassItem(service: KeychainConfiguration.serviceName,
                                              account: newAccountName!,
                                                accessGroup: KeychainConfiguration.accessGroup)

        // Save the password for the new item.
        try passwordItem.savePassword(newPassword!)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error updating keychain - \(error)")
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasSetup")
}
```

Here is what I currently have for Realm Encryption:

```
private func keyValue() -> Data
{
    var key = Data(count: 64)
    _ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
    }
    return key
}

private func securitySettings() -> Realm.Configuration
{  
    let key = keyValue()

    let config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)
    return config
}

private func setupObject()
{
    do {
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: securitySettings())

        let profile = UserProfile()
        profile.firstName = firstName
        profile.lastName = lastName
        profile.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        profile.gender = gender
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(profile)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Error opening realm: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: The username, password and realm encryption key information should be stored on the iOS Keychain. There is a tutorial on the Realm blog on that subject https://academy.realm.io/posts/tim-oliver-realm-cocoa-tutorial-on-encryption-with-realm/ Also Check the Realm Swift example for `Encryption` on Github. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift The very same code used on the Key storage can be used to store a String (email/password) so the tutorial should be really extensible. I recommend you to create a new Singleton class for managing the Keychain interactions.